# iPhone SDK: updating objects in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, nsarray

I have an NSArray of (Product) objects that are created by parsing an XML response from a server.

In the object, it has images, and text, and ints, URLs. etc.

There are 2 requests to the server
1: list of matching products from a search - small amount of detail
2: product details: the full details.

When the second request is parsed I am trying to update the existing object in the array.

```
- (void) setProduct:(Product *) _product atIndex: (int) index
{
    [_product retain];
    [productList replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:_product];
}
```

This doesn't seem to work as when I call update and table reloadData, the new values are not present.

Should I remove the object in the array first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You'll have to post more code from your data source methods. What you are doing here should work fine.
2. Your "retain" method is unnecessary, you're leaking `_product`.

Comment: Yep, I was just checking why it was not copying the new values across.

"Build and Analyze" doesn't catch this tough. 

the problem was the index was 0. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

replaceObjectAtIndex: is a method of NSMutableArray. So you would need to do make your productLists a NSMutableArray to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)updateprevious:(int)index withArg2:(NSString *)date
{
    NSLog(@"%@",date);
    NSLog(@"%d",index);

    for (int i=0;i < index; i++)
    {
        [final_X replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@""];
    }
}
```